# How to allow sorting in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, sorting, header

I have data from base, using Entity Framework. I don't use data binding source. I use this:

```
var caly = from m in stan.magazyn
                       from g in stan.gdzie
                       from p in stan.pracownik
                       where m.Gdzie_Jest == g.ID_Miasta
                       where m.Kto_Wprowadzil == p.ID_Pracownika
                       orderby m.Marka
                       select new { m.ID, m.Marka, m.Model, m.IMEI, m.Kolor, m.Od_Kogo, Sklep = g.Nazwa, m.Data_Wprowadzenia, m.Cena_Kupna, Dodał = p.login, m.Info };
            dataGridView1.DataSource = caly.ToList();
```

If I click in header in datagridview, I want that data sort. But don't work. What I must do? I'm trayed using linq, but dont work, its the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556242/linq-order-by-aggregate-in-the-select

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a sort Method to the Datagrid and set an expression for your sort.  And then rebind the datagrid after your sort expression is set and the data should be sorted.  You can setup your datagrid to sort by the value for each column, and call this method when you want to sort again.

Do the following:

Create an event handler for the grid's SortCommand event. In the method:
1. Get the sort key (the value you set in the Sort expression) from the SortExpression property of the DataGridSortCommandEventArgs argument.
2. Sort the data.
3. Rebind the data from the data source.

Example:

```
private void dataGridView1_SortCommand(object source, 
System.Web.UI.WebControls.dataGridView1SortCommandEventArgs e)
{
   dataGridView1.Sort = e.SortExpression;
   dataGridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: that's look good, but... I don't have SortCommand event... System.Web.UI.WebControls. My program is not web, is a windows form. I think that this is important.

Comment: DataGridView control must be bound to an IBindingList object to be sorted. this is error