# Using linq to group, select, and order a datatable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I want to use Linq to select and group DataTable rows... and I want to order those in a descending manner by the "Max" created date in each group... are there any improvements that could be made to this code, in particular can I make the OrderByDescending part of the Linq, for example using:

```
                    orderby {... something here...} descending
```

--- current code ---

```
        DataTable dt = ReadDataTable();
        var rows = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                    where row.Field<bool>("Active") == true
                    group row by new
                    {
                        CollectionId = row.Field<int>("CollectionId"),
                        CollectionName = row.Field<string>("CollectionName"),
                    } into grp
                    select new
                    {
                        CollectionId = grp.Key.CollectionId,
                        CollectionName = grp.Key.CollectionName,
                        MaxCreated = grp.Max(r => r.Field<DateTime>("Created"))
                    }).OrderByDescending(r => r.MaxCreated);
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [Linq order by aggregate in the select { }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556242/linq-order-by-aggregate-in-the-select)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`let` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) to hold intermediate results in a complex LINQ query, for use in subsequent sorts and selects.  In your case you can use it to store the *final result* for subsequent sorting.

I.e. you can rewrite your Linq without the `OrderByDescending()` lambda as follows:

```
DataTable dt = ReadDataTable();
var rows = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
           where row.Field<bool>("Active")
           group row by new
           {
               CollectionId = row.Field<int>("CollectionId"),
               CollectionName = row.Field<string>("CollectionName"),
           } into grp
           let result = new
           {
               CollectionId = grp.Key.CollectionId,
               CollectionName = grp.Key.CollectionName,
               MaxCreated = grp.Max(r => r.Field<DateTime>("Created")),
           }
           orderby result.MaxCreated descending
           select result;
```